# How can I group identical rows together automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm struggling to understand how to automatically group identical rows together in Excel. I don't need counts or anything fancy - I just need to bundle all rows that look the same (across multiple columns) together. An extract of the data is below (in CSV format):

EDIT: I forgot to mention that column A will be unique for every row.

```
29925S715114,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29995S715157,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29975S715206,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29915S715153,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,P15,P74,Y1
29965S715312,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29945S715339,BASE,267,342,402,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
299X5S715328,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29915S715105,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,P15,P74,Y1
29985S715182,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,P15,P74,Y1
29975S715285,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29965S715150,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,P15,P74,Y1
29945S715275,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29905S715189,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29975S715156,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,P15,P74,Y1
299X5S715152,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
299X5S715278,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29985S715344,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29945S715292,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29905S715287,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29975S715240,BASE,267,342,402,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29925S715288,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29955S715320,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29945S716491,BASE,267,342,407,435,446,640,680,762,AP,M6A,P74,P77,XSC,Y1
29935S715171,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29915S715170,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,P15,P74,Y1
29985S715098,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29915S715217,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29995S715272,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29995S715255,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29945S715325,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29985S715330,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29965S715116,BASE,267,342,435,640,670,680,762,AN,M6Z,P15,P74,Y1
29925S716490,BASE,267,342,407,435,446,640,680,762,AP,E9,M6A,P74,P77,XSC
```

Just eyeballing the data, you can see there are rows that look identical and some unique rows. I need to sort the uniques together. The full data set is thousands of rows long, so it's not realistic to do it "manually". Please let me know if this is possible in Excel as I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Pivot Tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)?

Comment: Sadly, I am not ... will this be useful in grouping them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy & Paste example data into LibreOffice Calc;
with a freshly started Calc it ends up in column A.

- Select the data.
- Click Menu:Data>Text to Columns
- Click to set Comma as delimiter
- Click ok
- Insert a single row above the data
- Select the data (now split in columns) AND the empty top row
- Select Menu:Data>Autofilter
- Click that little triangle on the first row, on each and every column starting at the first column, select e.g. "sort  ascending" in the menu that appears.
- The data will become sorted, leaving earlier sorting as "sub-sorting" if possible.

Now, all you need to do is do the autofilter sorting with e.g. VBA.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this did it, thank you. I applied your steps in Excel instead and it worked - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to "group" to enable easier sorting. You didn't mention that you want to remove duplicates. So just add another column where you concatenate your columns (except Column A).

So formula may look something like this:

```
=concat(B2:Q2)
```

Then sort (1) By your new column, then (2) by Col_A.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dumped your data into Excel and put a conditional format on it to highlight duplicates. There are no complete duplicates. In a beside the table I added the formula =TEXTSPLIT(A1,",") (you need office 365 or M365) to have that function. I then dragged it down to break all the data out.  You could then add layers of sorting or autofilter.

The results are below. I'm not sure if this the kind of thing you have in mind.
[image]

Hopefully, this might help.

Comment: Thank you so much - I forgot to mention that column A IS going to be unique for every row. The rest can be random. How does that change your solution above?

Comment: Excel versions prior to 365 has a Data > Split text to columns -function, as does LibreOffice Calc.